# Using data provider annotation to input username and password.getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error when executing in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

GETTING AN OUTOFBOUNDEXCEPTION WHEN EXECUTING IN SELENIUM.HAVE USED POM AND DATAPROVIDER HERE

public class Home extends Base {

```
@Test(dataProvider="getData")
public void homeBase(String Username,String password ) throws IOException
{
    driver=Initialization();
    driver.get("http://qaclickacademy.com");
    
    
    Landing_page lp = new Landing_page(driver); 
    lp.logIn().click();
    LoginPage log = new LoginPage(driver); 
    log.EmailId().sendKeys(Username);
    log.password().sendKeys(password);
    log.Go().click();
    
}


@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData()
{
    Object[][] data= new Object[0][1]; 
    
    //0th row
    data[0][0]="restricteduser@user.com";
    data[0][1]="restricted";
    
    
    return data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object[][] data= new Object[0][1];
```

this create object with 1 column and 0 row

instead if you want 1 row and 2 columns  you should use :

```
Object[][] data= new Object[1][2];
```